# How GET ID in UploadHandler.php blueimp

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I was changing UploadHandler.php like below & it worked fine.

But when I try to change the method `$id_ba=$_GET['id_ba']` or`$id_ba=$__POST['id_ba'];` to get VALUE POST ID an error appears.

I was trying to put it in index.php but got the same result.

```
$id_ba="3";// i want change this $id_ba=$_GET['id_ba'] or$id_ba=$__POST['id_ba'];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id_ba FROM TBL_1 WHERE id_ba='$id_ba'");

$new_folder = dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.'/files/'.$id_ba.'/';
if(!is_dir($new_folder))
{
    mkdir($new_folder, 0777,true);
}
else
{
    error_log($new_folder);
}

$this->response = array();
$this->options = array(
    'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
    'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.'/files/'.$id_ba.'/',
    'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.'/files/'.$id_ba.'/',
```

Please let me know how to get the value of ID.

Closed() thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Have You misspelled with $__POST ? If not, You should use $_POST ( only one underscore ) and provide POST data, please